# Typescript Clientside Namespacing over Multiple Files

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, namespaces

I'm writing a modular API that is accessed from the client side browser, and for the sake of organization I'd like to have these split into multiple files. What I would like is for the implementation to look like this:

```
<script src="dist/Api.js"></script> <-- Do I have to include all scripts?

//Browser console
var n = new Api();
var m = new Api.NamespacedClass();
var o = Api.property;
```

From what I've read on the documentation, it looks like the best way to do this is through `namespaces` and *not* `modules`, unless I'm supposed to do a combination of the two to get this working.

```
src/
├── models/
│   ├── Person.ts
│   ├── Thing.ts
│   Api.ts
```

**Person.ts**

```
namespace Api {
    export class Person {
        public create() {}
    }
}
```

**Thing.ts**

```
namespace Api {
    export class Thing {
        public create() {}
    }
}
```

**Api.ts**

```
//Insert references here
namespace Api {
    export class Api() { <--- I know this doesn't work.
        public property:string;
        constructor() {}
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to set up the correct structure. Any advice?

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? Do you need to include all scripts in the html file? Yes, if you're not using any module loader (which seems that you don't)

Comment: @NitzanTomer - that was part of it yes, but also is using Namespaces the correct way to do this? Or should I be using Modules? I'm not entirely clear on the difference

Comment: There's a whole section about [Namespaces and Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) where they explain the difference. It all depends on what you're after, but also take into account that the js world is going towards using modules and not namespaces.

Comment: The short answer is that modules are better for building large scale applications but require you to configure a module loader.  Namespaces are suitable for smaller applications.  However, even if you have a small project, most 3rd party libraries are moving to modules so you would need to configure a module loader to use them anyways.

Comment: Thank y'all for the clarifications!